# pipenv shell is not obeying the path it was originated

Tags: python, pipenv, pipenv-install

Suppose there is a parent folder `parent` and two child folders `child1` and `child2` when I run `pipenv install --python 3.9` in `child2` folder it still sets to `parent` folder when I run the command `pipenv shell`. How do I force to use the specific child folder path? Right now when I run `pipenv shell` in `child1` folder it is promoted as:

```
(Parent) ➜
```

rather than

```
(child1) ➜
```

Comment: I don't know if it's relevant, but did you by any chance create the virtual env before, then renamed/moved any of those folders?

Comment: There was a `venv` before in parent folder but I had removed it